# Python Desktop Shortcut (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, shortcut

We have a gui front end built in python with tkinter.

the main program is in `/home/user/program`
the gui is in `/home/user/program/gui`

the gui is launched in terminal by typing `python gui.py` and works as expected

i created a shortcut with this code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Comment
Terminal=false
Name=Name
Exec=lxterminal --command='bash -c "python /home/user/program/gui/gui.py; exec $SHELL"'
Type=Application
Icon=/home/user/program/gui/icon.png
Path=/home/user
StartupNotify=false
```

the gui.py seems to launch, but has an error in terminal stating:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/program/gui/gui.py", line 10, in <module>
    from program.task1 import scriptName
ImportError: No module named program.scriptName
```

I have no idea why this is so difficult to implement. If anyone has an easier way to do this please suggest it here. I have spent several hours trying to get this working. Thanks

Comment: Is `program` intended to be a package? Does it have an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: yes it is, it has an `__init__.py` file

Comment: ended up changing the shortcut to `Exec=/usr/bin/idle -r /home/user/program/gui/gui.py` and just dealing with minimising the IDLE window when it appears. it loads the GUI now.

Comment: @Nathan: your comment should probably be an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Exec=python3 /home/user/program/gui/gui.py

just spent some time on my own tkinter project

Comment: Your answer would be better if it explained why it works. Please provide some supplementary information to support your answer.